# Throws test fails when promise is rejected

Tags: javascript, ava

I have this function

```
export async function trivialAsyncFail() {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        reject("This is supposed to happen");
    });
}
```

And I have the following test to test it:

```
test("Async fail", async (t) => {
    const failedPromise = trivialAsyncFail();
    t.throws(failedPromise);
    await failedPromise;
});
```

However my test fails with message:

> Async fail
>
> Rejected promise returned by test
>
> Rejection reason:
>
> ```
> "This is supposed to happen"
> ```

I'm not sure if I have misunderstood how `t.throws` is supposed to work. I assumed that if you expect the promise to be rejected and it gets rejected the test should succeed.

Using ava 0.19

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://github.com/avajs/ava#user-content-throwsfunctionpromise-error-message):

> When testing a promise you must wait for the assertion to complete:
>
> ```
> test('rejects', async t => {
>   await t.throws(promise);
> });
> ```

So do `await t.throws(failedPromise)` instead of `await failedPromise`